# NN regression model predictions incomprehensible

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, regression

I'm trying to build a deep learning regression model for price prediction of AirBnB listings.
As a baseline, I started with a simple 3-layer NN as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD

epochs=100
batch_size=64

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model1.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))

# Compile the model
model1.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])

# Training the model
history = model1.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

This produced the following results:
[image: prediction vs ground truth]
[image: loss function]

```
Training RMSE: 57.5531
Validation RMSE: 60.5903

Training r2: -0.0345
Validation r2: -0.0767
```

As you can see, the model predicts all the listing in the 50 to 100 range with an RMSE of about $60.

What I have tried is:

- Tried several batch sizes
- Added extra layers
- Added dropout after each hidden layer
- Used kernel regularizers
- Learning rate optimization
- Callbacks (ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping)
- Many more...

All the results stayed roughly the same.

The only issue I see myself is that the dataset is way too small for this task.
[image: Dataset size]

I was wondering if there is any other fundamental flaw in my code/thinking?

Comment: Did you check against some „naive“ model such as linear regression or random forest. Small samples can be a problem with NN. Did you normalise training data? Otherwise your model looks okay.

Comment: The lack of normalization on the input data was indeed the problem here. Thank you for reminding me!